# Adding class to display hidden div on button click

Tags: javascript, forms, class, submit, addition

I have a class added to a div to change from display: none; to display: block on the press of a button, before the site submits the form.

I'm using this:

```
$('#save-btn').click(function() {

    var errors = true;

    if ($.trim($('#text-text').val()).length == 0) {
        errors = false;
        $('#text-text').addClass('error');
        $('.title-help').html('<?php echo Yii::t('yii', 'Please add some text to your image!') ?>').removeClass('hide');
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $('#text-text').offset().top - 100}, 400);
    }

    if (errors) {

    var $btn = $(this);
    fbLogin(function(){
            canvas.deactivateAll();
            canvas.renderAll();
              $("#loadingDiv").addClass("appear");
            $('#img-data').val(canvas.toDataURL());
            $btn.closest('form').submit();
    });
    }
    return false;
});
```

What I want to happen is the "appear" class to be added to the #loadingDiv, and the class is being loaded fine, however the form is being submitted instantly, so even though the class is being added to the div, it's not picking up the styles from the CSS in time...

How can I achieve this?

Any help much appreciated...

[Site can be seen here](http://www.olderawesomeperson.org)

Cheers,
Matt